# VS Code has colored one of my CSS selectors differently

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I'm working on a intro-level project where I have begun to use `aspect-ratio` as a way to apply a few rules to some images. What I can't figure out is why VS Code suggests, auto-completes, and links to MDN Reference just like every other valid CSS selector, but for whatever reason it colors the text white. I've seen this before and it just goes away by itself sometimes or I move onto to a different project and forget about it.

Screenshot of the 'aspect-ratio' selector being white as opposed to the light blue of all of the other selectors.

[image: 1]

I've re-written it a couple of times, moved the comments around and re-written the CSS selection entirely and it won't go away.

Comment: Does it matter? It still works right.

Comment: have you configured your own semantic coloring in like a `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` `textMateRules` or `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomiztions` `rules` in a settings.json or *.code-workspace file?